# How to restore OAuth client from Google API?

Tags: android, api, oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I'm using API for my Android game but I deleted the OAuth client in Google API by mistake.

I created a new ID client `OAuth` but now I can't put the `SHA1` importation fingerprint because

> This client ID is globally unique and is already in use (the one I deleted before).

How do I restore it, is there any workaround?

I can see the line where I deleted the ID client on Google Cloud Platform but I can't restore it in Google API's "manage resources" menu. There are no resources to restore. I guess I deleted only the ID client but not the project.

I'm so lost but I trust the community to help me with some tips!

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each service account has its own unique ID. When you delete service account it is purged after 30 days. During this period it can be restored by [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/).

Creating new service account with that same name has different bindings. 
So if you create new service account, [it is recommended to](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#deleting_and_recreating_service_accounts):

1. Remove all binding for old account.
2. Re-granting those roles to [new service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#granting_minimum).